What are the implications of changing the call index of an extrinsic on a runtime upgrade?
If I change the number x in #[pallet::call_index(x)] on a runtime upgrade, what will that impact?
The only thing I can come up with is Transact XCM instructions which use the SCALE encoding, but is there anything else I have to be aware of when changing the call indices?

Yeah it will change the call encoding, so any library that constructs calls with a hardcoded table instead of dynamically based on metadata will break. And as @AurevoirXavier said, any scheduled calls that are affected will break too. Usually it's a better practice just to add a new function at a new index and deprecate the one you want to remove.

Also check the scheduled calls.
For example, there is a referenda call pallet_x(call_y) with root origin.
If you change the y to ? and z to y. The call will be dispatched as original pallet_x(call_z) with root origin, this might  cause some problems.
